# server monitoring with snapshots for different metrics

Tags: monitoring

We are looking for a tool that can take snapshots of different things when system metrics reach a certrain threshold.

e.g. if the system load goes over 2, then:

- collect all running processes
- take thread dumps of running java VMs

We already have nagios/cacti in place. We need a tool that can collect arbitrary other information on the target host.

Any help appreciated.

**Note**: It should run on Debian systems.

Answer (score 1):

Since you wish to take custom snapshots in response to custom levels I would suggest taking a look to see if you can knock something together with python, (already installed on many Linux systems), and the python [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) library.

To install psutil just `sudo pip install psutil` should do the job nicely, you can then use a script to monitor the relevant system load and trigger the collection and logging of the information that psutil gives you plus the output of external tools if needed.

Possibly one of the following, (all based on psutil and customisable), might meet your needs with less effort:

- GGR https://github.com/google/grr
- Glances https://github.com/nicolargo/glances
- PSDash https://github.com/Jahaja/psdash

All the above software is Free, *(Libre & FOSS)*.